# Form validation not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<form name="ctrl.form" class="form-horizontal" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]"
      novalidate>

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : ctrl.form.inputName.$dirty && ctrl.form.inputName.$invalid}">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" ng-model="ctrl.app.name"
                   placeholder="Enter stack name" ng-disabled="ctrl.editMode" ng-required='true'
                   ng-minlength='3' ng-maxlength='32' required/>
        </div>
        <span ng-show="ctrl.form.inputName.$error.required && !ctrl.form.inputName.$pristine" class="help-block">Name is required</span>
        <span ng-show="ctrl.form.inputName.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Name is too short</span>
        <span ng-show="ctrl.form.inputName.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Name is too long</span>
        <span ng-show="ctrl.form.inputName.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Name has invalid characters</span>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : ctrl.hasServerErrors}">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="ctrl.isCreating"
                    ng-click="ctrl.SubmitForm()">{{ctrl.editMode ? 'Update' :
                ctrl.isCreating? 'Creating': 'Create'}}
            </button>
            <span ng-show="ctrl.hasServerErrors" class="help-block"
                  ng-repeat="serverError in ctrl.serverErrors">
            {{serverError}}
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="ctrl.showUpdateSuccessAlert">
        <strong>Successfully updated!</strong>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, the problem is, even though I have added the `required tag` to name, still when I click the submit button, the call goes to the backend service without showing that name is mandatory and has to be supplied.

What am I missing in this? Thanks!

Comment: How you are checking whether the form is valid or not. And what is `isCreating`? How you are disabling that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="" ng-show="ctrl.form.inputName.$dirty && ctrl.form.inputName.$invalid">
Message which you want to print.
</div>
```

Add this.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the form is valid before submitting the form.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="ctrl.form.$invalid"
                ng-click="ctrl.SubmitForm()">{{ctrl.editMode ? 'Update' :
            ctrl.isCreating? 'Creating': 'Create'}}
        </button>
```

$invalid will be true, when the form is not valid.

Comment: this works but this disables the create button itself till all the fields have been entered. What I really want is the browser level validation (HTML) which is not working. That is, the browser giving out messages like, Please enter a value or Please select an item in the list.

Comment: Then you have to mention this in your question properly.

Comment: @Rahi.Shah, I understand. This was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Okay, Now please ask a question with your proper requirement like you need validation at the browser level, not by angular js?